# Starting generated binary at Windows

Tags: go

I created a binary at some Windows 10 machine, and trying to start it in other machines, but keep getting the shown screen every time I launch the app, if I clicked "No" the app will start, but this is annoying and keep the end user confused, any thought how to avoid this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, it is Windows protection issue rather than Binary issue, where windows trying to protect from unknown binaries, the solution is very simple:

1. Rihgt click the app
2. Slect `Properties`
3. Check the `Unlock`
4. Click `Apply`
5. Click `OK`

[image]